# Play Websocket proxy for pub sub API

Tags: playframework, websocket, publish-subscribe

Trying to write a websocket in Play that will in turn make a request to another API to get a subscription and stream the data back to the client over the web socket.

I can easily create a simple websocket

```
def timeFeed = WebSocket.using[String] { implicit request =>
    val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
    val out = Enumerator.repeatM( play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(
      getTimeAndLog, 1000
    ))
    (in, out)
  }
```

how do a create an Enumerator from the feed I call on the API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def timeFeed = WebSocket.using[String] { implicit request =>
    val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
    val out = Enumerator.GenerateM( Future {
      getTimeAndLog
  })
    (in, out)
}
```

calling GenerateM instead of repeat will have the desired results